# Load file system icon at runtime C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have some C# code to get a icon from an embedded resource that works fine using a URI.

```cs
MyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/uif/tiles/Interface.ico")).Stream;
MyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

I want to achieve the same but with a icon from the file system c:\red.ico

Comment: [This constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-icon-ctor(system-string)) should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Your filepath");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy!? I did a LOT of searching and could not see this.

Comment: Your first look should be at the documentation for the class.  I Googled "Icon Class C#" to get the documentation I linked above.

Answer (score -1):

If you will use this icon in many forms, you can create a base form and set the base form icon in the constructor.
Then inherit new forms from the base form.
If you can't see the form designer, you can use the try-catch block in the base form.

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Icon = new Icon("Icon.ico");
    }
}
```

Inherited Form Example

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```